# Use separation of variables to find a solution $u= u(x,t)$...

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

[image: soln]

So I get up to the last paragraph of the solution. I can get the bases of the solution, but beyond that, I'm really confused as to what they did. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should type out the problem, rather than pasting an image, so that those of us who want to help can copy/paste this more easily.

Comment: I'm having second thoughts as to whether that's actually any better.  I retracted my downvote.

Comment: i would but im really bad at latex.. plus im not really asking for some detailed solution, just maybe some basic explanation of the last steps

Comment: yeah, and an image isn't prone to a typo, either.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the next step demands to develop the initial condition for $t=0$ in terms of the solutions for $X(x)$ as a linear combination or as a weighted integral over the parameter $c$.

However, in this case we are "lucky" that the initial condition itself is already such a solution. Thus $\pm\sqrt{c-1}=1$ resolves to $c=2$. Up to this point, the full solution is a linear combination of $e^{\pm\sqrt2\,t}·e^x$, the condition to fall to zero excludes the growing function $e^{\sqrt2\,t}·e^x$, leaving $e^{-\sqrt2\,t}·e^x$ as solution.